# Attachment REST API for Azure devops Board

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops, attachment

Scenario:
 IM trying to pass attachments from Service Now to a user story in Azure Devops Board

I am able to create a story from Servicenow by giving inputs in Servicenow ...so there is an option for attachment in Servicenow..If user want to attach something they can in Servicenow...but can this attachment be passed over to Azure Devops Board in the attachment section of the story is that possible, if so pls help

Comment: For azure devops, the api which can add the attchment is this [Attachments - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/Attachments/Create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#upload_a_text_file) , is this what you find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .but can this attachment be passed over to Azure Devops Board in the
>   attachment section of the story is that possible, if so pls help

Like **jessica** suggests, you can find Attachments relatet Rest API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). But as I know there's no Rest API supports directly passing attachment from `Service Now` to `Azure Devops Boards`.

So what you want is **not supported** for now. So far when we want to add attachment, it will fetch file only from local folders. Hope all above helps to resolve your puzzle.